# how to have custom quartiles and median for boxplot plotlyjs

Tags: javascript, boxplot, plotly.js

I have dynamic data. Based on length of data i.e even or odd. Based on that i need to calculate custom quartiles and median and pass in theplotly js boxplot.

here is what quartile generally does,

> Excel QUARTILE.EXC() Function / Wikipedia method 1 Use the median to
> divide the ordered data set into two halves. o If there is an odd
> number of data points in the original ordered data set, do not include
> the median (the central value in the ordered list) in either half. o
> If there is an even number of data points in the original ordered data
> set, split this data set exactly in half. The lower quartile value is
> the median of the lower half of the data. The upper quartile value is
> the median of the upper half of the data.
>
> Excel QUARTILE.INC() Function / Wikipedia method 2 Use the median to
> divide the ordered data set into two halves. o If there are an odd
> number of data points in the original ordered data set, include the
> median (the central value in the ordered list) in both halves. o If
> there are an even number of data points in the original ordered data
> set, split this data set exactly in half. The lower quartile value is
> the median of the lower half of the data. The upper quartile value is
> the median of the upper half of the data.

I am thinking this way,

Exclusive method:

```
function get_Q1_exclusive(data){
    N = data.length
    return }
```

Inclusive method:

```
function get_Q1_inclusive(data){
    N = data.length
    return }
```

After calculating manual quartiles, need to pass like this,

```
var data = [
  {
    q1: [3, 1],
    median: [4, 2],
    q3: [5, 3],
    mean: [4.5, 2.5],
    sd: [1, 1],
    lowerfence: [0.5, 0.5],
    upperfence: [9, 8],
    type: 'box'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

How to calculate inclusive/exclusive quartiles, median etc.?

Comment: So you want to have custom median, quartiles, lower and upper fence?

Comment: @SFDC yes exactly. I want calculation for median and quartiles, lower and upper fenc